# Postman showing different result than what is being sent ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, postman

Well, this is an unusual question and I am not sure where should I put in which site of stackoverflow, so if anybody can tell me I will gladly ask in that site.

**Question**

So, I am developing an ExpressJS backend and was testing that in postman.
The following code is of my interest.

```
response.status(200);
result.message = "Please Fill Registration Details";
result.data = {
    code: 010101
};
result.status = "Successful";
```

This is a simple code, no issue here, but when I checked in postman, the output is:

```
{
"message": "Please Fill Registration Details",
"data": {
    "code": 4161
},
"status": "Successful"
}
```

[image]

> How did the code 010101 change to 4161 ?

I first thought that postman was considering 010101 to be binary and converting it to decimal, but the decimal value is 21 and hexadecimal number is 15.

So, how is this happening ? Has anyone experienced this before ?
I still need to check this API in production and in actual devices.
I will update my findings.

Comment: Don't use leading zeroes on your decimal numbers or use a string!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It consider `010101` as an octal number, that is how JavaScript works. The reason it consider that as an octal number is because it is not surrounded by the quotes.

Here is an example of JavaScript:

```js
console.log(010101);  //4161
```

So, to fix your code, surround your value in quotes:

```
result.data = {
    code: "010101"
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is something I never knew. This has saved me a lot of time in future.

Comment: @SiddhantGhosh Glad to help :).

Comment: Quotes make it a string, so in type based system this will not work on some clients.

Comment: Imagine a test driven development, how to make the return property be a number and have the expecting value...

Answer (score 1):

Javascript understands numbers starting with 0 to be octal (base 8). 10101 in Octal has a decimal value of 4161. If you want to pass the code with a leading zero, pass it as a string "010101".

Answer (score 0):

You selected JSON formatting in postman...

Besides that JS does not follow type rules,

let var1 = 010101;
let var2 = Number(010101);

Comment: Javascript does follow type rules. Just not the same rules as anyone else.

Comment: noted by that fact you can not tell to anyone that JS follows type rules, it's not type-based language...

Comment: JS is a dynamically typed language. It has types, those types follow rules. The rules define automatic conversion between types. This automatic conversion is not always consistent or intuitive, however it is a set of rules, and a set of types.